# Large block coefficient-wise multiplication fails in Eigen library C++

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, access-violation

I've read through a lot of the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html), however if you find something which I've missed that can explain away my issue I'll be pleased. For background, I'm compiling on x86 Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2015 using the 3.2.7 Eigen Library. The 3.2.7 version is from May and while there have been releases since then, I haven't seen anything in the [changelog](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=ChangeLog) that would indicate my issue has been solved.

The issue seems to only appear for matrices above a certain size. I don't know if this is a byproduct of something specific to my system or something inherent to Eigen.

The following code produces an access violation in both Debug and Release mode.

```
int mx1Rows = 255, cols = 254;
{//this has an access violation at the assignment of mx2
        Eigen::MatrixXd mx1(mx1Rows, cols);
        Eigen::MatrixXd mx2(mx1Rows + 1, cols);
        Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixXd, -1, -1, false> temp = mx2.topRows(mx1Rows);
        mx2 = temp.array() * mx1.array();//error
}
```

I believe the assignment of the coefficient-wise multiplication to be safe since the result should be [aliased](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html).

This issue becomes interesting when mx1Rows is reduced to the value 254, then the access violation doesn't appear. That's correct, the mx2 dimensions of 256 by 254 produce the problem but the dimensions 255 by 254 don't. If I increase the column size I can also get the access violation, so the problem likely has something to do with the total number of entries. The issue appears even if mx1 and mx2 are filled with values, having filled matrixes is not necessary to reproduce the issue.

Similar code that does not assign the topRows() block to temp does not produce the access violation in Release mode. I believe there is something more to this since I originally identified this issue in code that was considerably more complex and it only appeared after a certain number of loops (the matrix sizes were consistent between loops). There is so much going on in my code that I haven't been able to isolate the conditions under which the access violation only appears after a certain number of loops.

What I am curious to know is

1) Am I using Eigen in some obviously wrong way?

2) Are you able to reproduce this issue? (what is your environment particulars?)

3) Is this a bug in the Eigen library?

It's easy enough to work around this problem by assigning the block to a temporary matrix instead of a block, even if it is inefficient, so I'm not interested in hearing about that.

Comment: Looks like a bug assuming the negative 1 indexes are allowed and they seem to be. If you initialize the matrices you will see that even at small values of mx1Rows and cols it is putting garbage in the array mult. Running `temp.array().eval().array()` works fine. You are not aliasing outside of the data. It does execute in x64 but incorrectly. It just doesn't fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `temp` references the coefficients held by `mx2`, but in the last assignment, `mx2` is first resized before the expression gets evaluated. Therefore, during the actual evaluation of the expression, `temp` references garbage. More precisely, here is what is actually generated (in a simplified manner):

```
double* temp_data = mx2.data;
free(mx2.data);
mx2.data = malloc(sizeof(double)*mx1Rows*cols);
for(j=0;j<cols;++j)
  for(i=0;i<mx1Rows;++i)
    mx2(i,j) = temp_data[i+j*(mw1Rows+1)] * mx1(i,j);
```

This is called an [aliasing issue](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html).

You can workaround by evaluating the expression in a temporary:

```
mx2 = (temp.array() * mx1.array()).eval();
```

Another solution is to copy `mx2.topRows(.)` into a true `MatrixXd` holding its own memory:

```
MatrixXd temp = mx2.topRows(mx1Rows);
mx2 = temp.array() * mx1.array();
```

Yet another solution is to evaluate into `temp` and resize afterward:

```
Block<MatrixXd, -1, -1, false> temp = mx2.topRows(mx1Rows);
temp = temp.array() * mx1.array();
mx2.conservativeResize(mx1Rows,cols);
```

Comment: This sort of issues always occur in situation where you keep a reference to an object (rather than an object), which is manipulated elsewhere.

Comment: It seems reasonable to me that componentwise multiplication shouldn't require a reallocation unless there is no concept of capacity in Eigen (like capacity vs size for strings in the STL). Is that basically the problem? The LHS no longer has the same dimensions so it's getting reallocated and this becomes a problem because the RHS is not using aliased Matrix multiplication because the array interface is used? If this is the case then perhaps the following would succeed without reallocation or corruption? 

mx2.topRows(mx1Rows) = mx2.topRows(mx1Rows).array() * mx1.array();

Comment: This is exactly the latest solution I proposed, but using `temp` as a shortcut. Also, please bear in mind that by default, MatrixXd has a column-major storage, so the columns of `temp` are not sequentially stored in memory. So here `conservativeResize` first needs to pack the columns through memory copies, before freeing the last bytes. Of course, you can also omit resizing, and use `temp` instead of `mx2` in the remaining computations.

Comment: You've been very helpful ggael, thank you. I believe you have mostly answered the 3 questions I laid out for giving a correct answer. I hope you don't take it personally but I must disagree that your last solution is the same as what I wrote because the difference is the answer to my question. The code I placed in the comment doesn't involve new memory allocation where creating a temp matrix does. If you use a temp matrix you are effectively doing explicit aliasing. Since the element-wise product doesn't alias and the LHS is the wrong dimension for the result so an allocation occurs.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but in the last solution I proposed, `temp` was implicitly defined as in the original question. I'll clarify the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like a bug that affects small dimensions as well. Remove the comment in the bug inducing line to get correct results.

Correction. As ggael's answer points out, it is aliasing. It's of the type often encountered using auto to create a temp that is later used on the same object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{//this has an access violation at the assignment of mx2
    //const int mx1Rows = 255, cols = 254;
    const int mx1Rows = 3, cols = 2;
    Eigen::MatrixXd mx1(mx1Rows, cols);
    int value = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < mx1Rows; i++)
            mx1(i,j)=value++;
    Eigen::MatrixXd mx2(mx1Rows + 1, cols);
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < mx1Rows+1; i++)
            mx2(i,j)=value++;
    Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixXd, -1, -1> temp = mx2.topRows(mx1Rows);
    mx2 = temp.array()/*.eval().array()*/ * mx1.array();r
    std::cout << mx2.array() << std::endl;
}

// with /*.eval().array()*/ uncommented
//0 30
//7 44
//16 60

// Original showing bug
//-0 -4.37045e+144
//-1.45682e+144 -5.82726e+144
//-2.91363e+144 -7.28408e+144
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem, but merely remarks about it in a way that is perhaps appropriate for a comment, but not an answer.

Comment: @Walter  Agreed. It's the type of aliasing that also occurs on multi-line "temps" when using auto. Effectively `Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixXd, -1, -1> temp` does that rather than declaring temp a MatrixXd and using the Block on the right.  I should have seen that.